# Writing class for polling network devices using SNMP

Tags: c#

I have to write a class, which requests info from the network device using SNMP.
The first thing is to find out the device kind.
The second - a poll of the device.

I wanted to write a class that only needs the IP address, and it will be collect the information depending on the device kind.

But i can't understand how to do it in the best way.

I don't like this, because there are two SNMP classes.

May be there is a simple code, how it is realized in different applications.

Now i have something like this template:

```
class NetworkDevice
{
    SNMP snmp;
    GenericDevice gd;
    ....
    public string GetObjectID() 
    {
         return snmp.Get(mib).ToString();
    }

    public void Scan()
    {
        string obj_id = GetObjectID();
        if(obj_id.StartsWith(".1.3.6.1.4.1.15")
            gd = new DeviceKind_1(ip_addr);
        if(obj_id.StartsWith(".1.3.6.1.4.1.181")
            gd = new DeviceKind_2(ip_addr);
        gd.Scan();
    }
}

class GenericDevice
{
    private SNMP snmp;
    private DeviceInfo Info;
    ....
    public void Scan()
    {

    }
}

class DeviceKind_1 : GenericDevice
{
    ....
    public void override Scan()
    {
        DeviceInfo.DEVICE_SPECIAL_PARAM_1 = snmp.Get(mib);
        ....
    }
    ....
}

class DeviceKind_2 : GenericDevice
{
    ....
    public void override Scan()
    {
        DeviceInfo.DEVICE_SPECIAL_PARAM_1 = snmp.Get(mib);
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

*** Code was edited ***

Comment: I would recommend using a solution such as SharpSNMP library

Comment: I use it in SNMP class. SNMP class is an interface for me.

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems:

- snmp is used twice, as you already mentioned. Why don't you inherit  NetworkDevice from GenericDevice  and remove the snmp variable from NetworkDevice?
- snmp is not used in GenericDevice (yet?) ... in that case you can remove it from GenericDevice and only keep it in NetworkDevice. Otherwise, only keep it in GenericDevice and make it protected (or use get/set methods).

The good thing is you have multiple classes, so it must be easy to keep all generic functionality in GenericDevice, all network specific functionality in NetworkDevice and have separate classes for specific devices.

Consider using an (abstract) Factory pattern to generate the correct class. This is a design pattern.

Comment: Oh! It's my mistake. Snmp using in not used in GenericDevice. DeviceKind_1 and DeviceKind_2. In GenericDevice must be   private SNMP snmp;